# Generic factory class instantiation

Tags: java, generics, factory-pattern

If have a TCP/UDP communications factory as such

```
public enum IoFactory {
  // Singleton
  INSTANCE;

  public <T> Io<T> create(T type, TransportProtocol protocol) {
    ...
    return ...;
  }
}
```

which creates `Io` interfaces:

```
public interface Io<T> {
  public void send(T msg);
  public T receive();
}
```

however, when I create an instance of `Io` with

```
IoFactory factory = IoFactory.INSTANCE;     
Io<TestMessage> u = factory.create(TestMessage.class, TransportProtocol.UDP);
```

I get a compilation error saying that the correct instantiation should be

```
Io<Class<TestMessage>> u = factory.create(TestMessage.class, TransportProtocol.UDP);
```

what's the deal?

Comment: `TestMessage.class` is of type `Class<TestMessage>`, and not of type `TestMessage` (it is the class object, NOT an object of type `TestMessage`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create()` accepts a `T`, as a parameter and return `Io<T>` as return value.

However, in your code, you send `TestMessage.class` as a parameter.

`TestMessage.class` is of type `Class<TestMessage>`, and not of type `TestMessage` (it is the class object, NOT an object of type `TestMessage`).

So, the compiler "understands" that `T` is `Class<TestMessage>`, and expects `Io<Class<TestMessage>>` should be the return type from `create()`, but you then reassign it to `u` - which is a variable of type `Io<TestMessage>` - the wrong type.

Answer (score 1):

I think the signature you're looking for is:

```
public <T> Io<T> create(Class<T> type, TransportProtocol protocol) {
```

Comment: Sure is! Yeah that makes a lot of sense